# How to simplify this summation, or express as integral? $\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(t+ax)^2+4}}$

Tags: summation, periodic-functions

How to simplify this summation, or express as integral?
$$f(x)=\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(t+ax)^2+4}}$$
$a$ is a constant, say, 24.
$$f(x)=\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(t+24x)^2+4}}$$

Comment: If converges to some value you can write it as an integral

Comment: Of course, you can always write it as $+\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Just to make an answer from sos440's comment: From the [integral test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) you get:

$$\sum_{t=1}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(t+24x)^2+4}} > \int_1^\infty  \frac1{\sqrt{(t+24x)^2+4}} dt = \infty$$

because $\frac1{\sqrt{(t+24x)^2+4}} \approx \frac 1x$  for $x\rightarrow\infty$ and $\int_1^\infty \frac 1x dx$ diverges. Because each summand of $f(x)$ is positive, also $$\sum_{t=-\infty}^\infty\frac1{\sqrt{(t+24x)^2+4}} = \infty$$.